# AVPlayer in UICollectionViewCell plays sound but doesn't show video

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

I have a UICollectionViewController with fullscreen cells that scroll horizontally. Within each cell is another collectionView that scrolls vertically. The header cell of the collectionView has an AVPlayer pulling a video from a URL. Currently only the audio plays but the video doesn't.

The below AVPlayer setup and observers are of the same code I've used numerous other times within the app outside of a UICollectionViewCell without problem. The player frame size checks out, and the audio plays and loops as expected, so the observers seem to be triggering properly.

Relevant code:

```
var post: Post! {
    didSet {
        videoURL = URL(string: post.videoURL)
        setupVideoObservers()
    }
}

var videoURL: URL! {
    didSet {
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    }
}

@objc dynamic var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!

var videoPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

let videoContainerView = UIView()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupCell()
}


func setupCell() {
    addSubview(videoContainerView)
    videoContainerView.anchor(top: topAnchor,
                              right: rightAnchor,
                              bottom: bottomAnchor,
                              left: leftAnchor)

    videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
    videoPlayerLayer.frame = frame
    videoPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

    videoContainerView.layer.addSublayer(videoPlayerLayer)
}

func setupVideoObservers() {
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "videoPlayer.currentItem.status", options: .new, context: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerReachedEndOfVideo(notification:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForegroundNotification), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "videoPlayer.currentItem.status" {
        videoPlayer.play()
    }
}

@objc func playerReachedEndOfVideo(notification: NSNotification) {
    let seekTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1000)
    videoPlayer.seek(to: seekTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
    videoPlayer.play()
}

@objc func appWillEnterForegroundNotification() {
    videoPlayer.play()
}
```

All the other SO solutions to problems of AVPlayer audio without video that I've come across haven't applied. If anyone has any insight it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar issue. Try setting the frame of the `AVPlayerLayer` to a `CGRect()` of your desired size after you fill the contents. Also you may want to make a `Dispatch.Queue` Asynchronous call for your `didSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm setting the AVPlayerLayer frame to the cell frame as it is and am experiencing the issue. Good idea on the asynchronous call.

Comment: What I meant is to try setting the videoPlayerLayer.frame to lets say CGRect(0, 0, width, height) after you call videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)  in the didSet and both of those in an asych call. I am currently doing something very similar and had the exact same issue.

Comment: Interesting. I'll play around with it now and follow up with the results. Thanks again.

Comment: You're my new favorite person — after a bit of refactoring your suggestion works perfectly. Massively appreciate it.